# How to take screenshot from iPhone using command line

Tags: ios, screen-capture

I'm used to taking screenshots from android devices using the adb command line. Is there a way to do the same with the iphone?

Comment: Which command line? On the iPhone itself, while being logged in through ssh?

Comment: Terminal command line on mac that's connected by usb to the physical iPhone

Comment: He means from the terminal.app in MacOS. He (and I) want the same functionality you got when you do XCode -> Devices -> Screenshot

Answer (score -1):

Tha's very easy
1. Choose the screen from that you want to make a Screenshot
2. Pressing the home and the sleep/wake buttons together

Comment: i'm looking to do it from command line

Comment: This only works with a jailbroken iphone (no hint in your title that you have a jailbroken iphone..). you need to install **Cycript**. If you do so, simply type **screenshot output.jpg** to make a screenshot of your working directory.